# Defining a namespace with ExtJs5

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I'm using ExtJs 5 and SenchaCmd.

In a package, I defined several classes in several files like this:

```
// Bar1.js
Ext.define('Foo.Bar1', {
   ...
});

// Bar2.js
Ext.define('Foo.Bar2', {
   ...
});
```

Now I'd like to just "augment" the Foo namespace with some general tools like this :

```
Ext.ns('Foo');
Foo.tool1 = function() { ... }
Foo.tool2 = function() { .... }
Foo.generalProp1 = 42;
(...)
```

What would be the better place and practive to declare this so that the Sencha Compiler embeds this file too?

Is it possible to "require" (in a way) a namespace like we require a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `statics` from new Ext:

```
Ext.define('Foo', {
    // declare static members
    statics: {
        method: function(){ return "static method"; }
    }
});

// Define class under Foo namespace
Ext.define('Foo.OtherClass', {
    method: function(){ return "instance method"; }
});

// Create instance of Foo.OtherClass
var o = Ext.create('Foo.OtherClass');

// Use static member
console.log(Foo.method());

// Use instance member
console.log(o.method());
```

Then you can treat your `Foo` namespace like class, and place as any other class.
Then obviously you can also require that namespace, because it is also class.

Comment: Thanks. I have 2 questions :  
1/ Must I declare those two namespaces ('Foo' and 'Foo.OtherClass') in the same file?  
2/ If I want to add some shortcuts of functions from Foo.OtherClass in the "Foo" namespace, is it complicated?

Comment: 1. No - define Foo in /Foo.js and OtherClass in Foo/OtherClass.js; 
2. You can pass callback to `Ext.define` which is called after class is created, eg.: `Ext.define('Name', {}, function(nameClass){})`. In this callback you can create shortcuts.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r59wopn5/2/